# Page navigation with php

Tags: php, redirect, navigation, hyperlink

I am trying to create a dynamic website, the index.php includes the following code in the content area of the website:

```
<?PHP

// if undefined then define
 if(!$od || $od == ""){
 $od = "news";
 }
// check if exists prep
 $link = 'incs'."/".$od.$ext;
 flush();
 $fp = fopen($link, "r");

// check if inclusion file not exists then return error
 if (!$fp) {
 echo "An error has ocurred while processing your request. The file linked as ?od=".$od." does not appear to exist.";
 }

// if exists then return parse
 else { 
 fclose($fp);
 include 'incs'."/".$od.$ext;
 }

echo '</body>'."\n";
echo '</html>'."\n";

?>
```

I also have various links throughout the site to pages like register, login, etc.
Those links point to pages like ?od=register, ?od=login, etc.

The website will pull the default file for me, news, and display that in my content section of my website, but when I click register, the url in the address bar DOES change to /?od=register, but the default news remains in the content section, is there an error in the code above? Or am I just missing something?

P.S. `$ext` is defined in my config file as `inc.php`, which is included at the top of the index page.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that this is very insecure - you are making a GET request, access the variables through the `$_GET` array ie `$od = $_GET['od']`

Comment: I would make it secure by checking if the $op is inarray(); Example if(in_array($op, $pagenames)){ //perform inclusion } EDIT: syntax error

Comment: Yep, pretty much with the fopen a malicious user can determine what files are on the server, example: example.com/?op=../index  By doing that I could possibly go back a directory

Comment: what do i need to set $op and $pagenames as before preforming the inclusion? and does that mean i need to get rid of fopen completely??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to define $od with a $_GET['od'] or $_REQUEST['od']

```
$od = $_GET['od'];
// if undefined then define
 if(!$od || $od == ""){
 $od = "news";
```